# Modifying Ckeditor with additional plugins in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I installed CKeditor gem on my rails 3 application . Now I want to add some additional plugins to it . I looked up ckeditor documentation and it states that the plugin files need to go where ckeditor was unzipped. I am new to rails and I am trying to locate my ckeditor files but I can't find them in the app directory except the model files created when I installed ckeditor .

Where should I place files for my custom ckeditor plugin to include them in editor on initialization ?

**EDIT :** 
As per the answer below added plugin files in the mentioned directory. Trying to load the plugin with the following command in config.js for ckeditor :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('insert_blank','http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/plugins/insert_blank/', 'plugin.js');
var temp = CKEDITOR.registered; 
alert(temp) ; 
  config.extraPlugins = 'insert_blank' ; 
  config.toolbar =
    [

        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','-','Italic' ] },

        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','insert_blank.btn'
                 ] },

   ];
   config.toolbar.push(['insert_blank.btn']);
   config.height = 300 ; 
   config.width = 300 ; 
   config.removePlugins =  'elementspath,resize' ;


};
```

This is my plugin.js file :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'insert_blank',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {


              editor.addCommand('InsertBlank',
                {
                  exec function(editor)
                  {
                    editor.insertHtml( '__');
                  }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'insert_blank.btn',
        {
            label: 'Insert Blank',
            command: 'InsertBlank',
            icon: this.path + 'images/blank.png'
        } );
       }
} ) ;
```

I am giving an absolute path only because I am in dev , will change that later . The alert above produces 'not defined' . I checked my server log and the files are found by the application server . Looks like I am not able to add the plugin correctly to ckeditor . Any ideas as to what might be going wrong ?

**Update** : There was some error with my plugin.js . Everything else is fine .

Comment: How did you install ckeditor? I am not familiar with ruby, but normally you "install" ckeditor by unzipping it to the site dir.

Comment: Rails has the concept of Gems.I just found the ckeditor folder inside the gems directory but it does not have the plugins folder . Should I create one and place my new plugins inside it ?

Comment: I don't know Gems either :P but yes, I think you should just create the folder and you are up to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put all your plugins in the assets folder of your application.

Create a folder in `app/assets/javascript/ckeditor/plugins` and place all your plugin files here.

Comment: I did this , modified my config.js file to include the plugin . My ckeditor fails to load because of it . Can I view the error logs for ckeditor anywhere ? I am following this documentation : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins

Comment: Check the browser console for any errors. You should also check if the plugin js files are being included.

Comment: Hi , I made new additions to the question above , please check . Thanks for you time .

Comment: Can you check your html source to see if the file is being included?

Comment: Yes the plugin.js file is included . I have edited above to include the entire config.js file .

Comment: This seems to be a javascript/ckeditor issue and not a rails problem. The only last thing I can think of is maybe you need to load the `plugin.js` file before the `ckeditor` files... but not sure